# View the full dataset within ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How do I view the full dataset that is within ADF and not just a preview?

Within ADF, (Azure Data Factory) there is an option to 'preview the data'. How would I view this data in full?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Per my experience, I'm afraid we can see the full data of the dataset. Some time the source dataset may be very large.

Comment: Ok I have figured that you must make a copy of it and send it to another database like Cosmosdb etc

Comment: Yeah, but since you can access the SQL database, why don't you see the data  directly with the database tools? By the way, can I port it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, I'm afraid we can see the full data of the dataset. Some time the source dataset may be very large.

I'm glad that you figured that: "make a copy of it and send it to another database like Cosmosdb etc".